# Retrofit Gson custom serialize for specific attribute in nested json

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson, retrofit

I have this json (it's much complex than this)
The problem is that "past_ings" attribute may be an object or array of objects.

```
query: {
  count: 2,
  created: "2015-11-17T11:44:06Z",
  lang: "en-US",
  results: {
    Scorecard: [
       {
          past_ings: {
             s: {},
             d: {}
          }
       }
     ]
   }
 }

query: {
  count: 2,
  created: "2015-11-17T11:44:06Z",
  lang: "en-US",
  results: {
    Scorecard: [
       {
          past_ings: [
             {
                s: {},
                d: {}
             },
             {
                s: {}
             }
           ]
        }
     ]
   }
 }
```

I use retrofit and gson, by creating POJO's with @SerializedName but it doesn't work "part_ings".

My question is Could I use TypeAdapter just to serialize one attribute "past_ings" and let default Gson serialize the rest? because it's too complex to use TypeAdapter for all the incoming objects.

Edit: I define past_ings as below

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("past_ings")
private List<PastIngs> pastIngses;
```

I get this error `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2241 path $.query.results.Scorecard[0].past_ings`

Comment: See this answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/33006947/1904517

Answer (score 0):

Why not put one value in array and serialize it?
Your `past_ings` may be an array of objects or one object. So create `ArrayList` and put everything you need to put in `past_ings` there. If there is one value, your ArrayList will be serialized to `JSONArray` with one object.

Comment: It would throw Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT, because if past_ings has one value, it will be an object and can't be serialized to JSONArray. Also, the API can't be changed to be an array.

Comment: _if past_ings is one value, it will be an Object and can't be serialized to JSONArray_ In your POJO create 'Arraylist' past_ings. It will be serialized as JSONArray, no metter one value inside or many.

Comment: Ok, try another way. **JsonElement pastIngs = rootObejct.get("pastIngs");** JsonElement is a basic GSON element, from which JsonObject and JsonArray are inherited.