# How to parse a JSON reply when using retrofit when the reply is sometimes an object and sometimes an array?

Tags: java, json, retrofit, rx-java

I am using Retrofit to get a JSON reply.

Here are parts of my implementation -

```
@GET("/api/report/list")
Observable<Bills> listBill(@Query("employee_id") String employeeID);
```

and the class Bills is -

```
public static class Bills {
    @SerializedName("report")
    public ArrayList<BillItem> billItems;
}
```

The `BillItem` class is as follows -

```
public static class BillItem {
    @SerializedName("id")
    Integer entryID;
    @SerializedName("employee_id")
    Integer employeeDBID;
    @SerializedName("type")
    String type;
    @SerializedName("subtype")
    String subtype;
    @SerializedName("date")
    String date;
    @SerializedName("to")
    String to;
    @SerializedName("from")
    String from;
    @SerializedName("amount")
    Double amount;
    @SerializedName("location")
    String location;
    @SerializedName("remark")
    String remark;
    @SerializedName("ispaid")
    String isPaid;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    String updateAt;
}
```

The problem is sometimes the REST API returns an Array of `BillItem` objects, but sometimes it is just a `key-value` pair. How does one handle such a situation?

When this response is received, everything works fine because the `JSONArray` gets mapped to the `ArrayList<BillItem>` -

```
{
   "emp":{
      "id":41,
      "name":"",
      "email":"",
      "created_at":"2016-02-01 10:36:38",
      "updated_at":"2016-02-01 10:36:38"
   },
   "report":[
      {
     "id":175,
     "employee_id":41,
     "type":"Travel",
     "subtype":"Car",
     "date":"2016-02-02 00:00:00",
     "to":"gaha",
     "from":"hshsj",
     "amount":"64",
     "location":"",
     "remark":"shhs",
     "ispaid":false,
     "created_at":"2016-02-01 13:52:52",
     "updated_at":"2016-02-01 13:52:52"
      },
      {
     "id":179,
     "employee_id":41,
     "type":"Travel",
     "subtype":"Car",
     "date":"2016-02-01 00:00:00",
     "to":"Gsh",
     "from":"Dgdh",
     "amount":"7646",
     "location":"",
     "remark":"Shsh",
     "ispaid":false,
     "created_at":"2016-02-01 14:39:48",
     "updated_at":"2016-02-01 14:39:48"
      }
   ]
}
```

But, sometimes the response is this, and it gives a `JsonSyntaxException` -

```
{
   "emp":{
      "id":41,
      "name":"",
      "email":"",
      "created_at":"2016-02-01 10:36:38",
      "updated_at":"2016-02-01 10:36:38"
   },
   "report":{
      "1":{
     "id":175,
     "employee_id":41,
     "type":"Travel",
     "subtype":"Car",
     "date":"2016-02-02 00:00:00",
     "to":"gaha",
     "from":"hshsj",
     "amount":"64",
     "location":"",
     "remark":"shhs",
     "ispaid":false,
     "created_at":"2016-02-01 13:52:52",
     "updated_at":"2016-02-01 13:52:52"
      },
      "2":{
     "id":179,
     "employee_id":41,
     "type":"Travel",
     "subtype":"Car",":"2016-02-01 00:00:00",
     "to":"Gsh",
     "from":"Dgdh",
     "amount":"7646",
     "location":"",
     "remark":"Shsh",
     "ispaid":false,
     "created_at":"2016-02-01 14:39:48",
     "updated_at":"2016-02-01 14:39:48"
      },
      "0":{
     "id":181,
     "employee_id":41,
     "type":"Travel",
     "subtype":"Car",
     "date":"2016-02-01 00:00:00",
     "to":"ggg",
     "from":"vg",
     "amount":"0",
     "location":"",
     "remark":"cvv",
     "ispaid":false,
     "created_at":"2016-02-01 17:43:43",
     "updated_at":"2016-02-01 17:43:43"
      },
      "3":{
     "id":182,
     "employee_id":41,
     "type":"Travel",
     "subtype":"Car",
     "date":"2016-02-01 00:00:00",
     "to":"Haha",
     "from":"Ahah",
     "amount":"0",
     "location":"",
     "remark":"Ahah",
     "ispaid":false,
     "created_at":"2016-02-01 17:53:58",
     "updated_at":"2016-02-01 17:53:58"
      }
   }
}
```

How, does one deal with such a reply?

Comment: See the GSON type adapter in this answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/33006947/1904517

Comment: can't you fix the api to always return an array, even when there's only 1 item, or even when there's 0?

Comment: @Gavriel unfortunately, I do not have any controls over the API.

Comment: @iagreen can you explain something about the implementation in your answer?

Comment: It uses a `TypeAdapter` to always return a list,  It peeks at the value.  If it is an array, it processes as usual, if not, it reads the value but returns it in a single element list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a Gson deserializer you can check the type in the JsonElement:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(BillItem.class, new BillItemDeserializer())
            .registerTypeAdapter(Bills.class, new BillsDeserializer())
            .create();

RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            //...
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson));

public class BillsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<StringList> {

    public Bills deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
         BillItemList value = new BillItemList();
         if (json.isJsonArray()) {
             for (JsonElement element : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
                 value.add(gson.fromJson(element, BillItem.class));
             }
         } else {
             value.add(gson.fromJson(element, BillItem.class));
         }
         return value;
     }
}
```

See example: [Gson deserialization - Trying to parse a JSON to an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296427/gson-deserialization-trying-to-parse-a-json-to-an-object)

Comment: What would the `Deserialization` do?

Can you also tell what should be my `API` and `class definitions`?

Comment: As suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30899048), I defined a new class -
`public class BillItemList {
        @SerializedName("report")
        public ArrayList<BillItem> billItemsList;
}`

with the GSon definition as -

`        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(BillItemList.class, new StringListDeserializer())
                .create();`

Comment: And the deserializer as - 

    `public class StringListDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<BillItemList> {@Override public BillItemList deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws
                JsonParseException {
            BillItemList value = new BillItemList();
            if (json.isJsonArray()) {  for (JsonElement element : json.getAsJsonArray()) { value.add(element.getAsString()); }
            } else { value.add(json.getAsString());
            }
            return value;
        }
    }`

Comment: @yadav_vi, I thought about something similar, but I think instead of getAsString you can use Gson to deserialize the BillItem objects as well, seem my update

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35147104/2863440) by [@Gavriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661589/gavriel) a custom `Deserializer` needs to be written.

Here is my implementation (it might contain superfluous code) -

The Actual `API` definition -

```
public interface ServerAPI {
    public static final String ENDPOINT = "http://xyz";

    @GET("/api/report/list")
    Observable<Bills> listBill(@Query("employee_id") String employeeID);

    public static class BillItem {
        @SerializedName("id")
        public Integer entryID;
        @SerializedName("employee_id")
        public Integer employeeDBID;
        @SerializedName("type")
        public String type;
        @SerializedName("subtype")
        public String subtype;
        @SerializedName("date")
        public String date;
        @SerializedName("to")
        public String to;
        @SerializedName("from")
        public String from;
        @SerializedName("amount")
        public Double amount;
        @SerializedName("location")
        public String location;
        @SerializedName("remark")
        public String remark;
        @SerializedName("ispaid")
        public String isPaid;
        @SerializedName("created_at")
        public String createdAt;
        @SerializedName("updated_at")
        public String updateAt;
    }

    public static class Bills {
        @SerializedName("report") // This seems to serve no purpose.
        public ArrayList<BillItem> billItems = new ArrayList<>(); // It was needed to initialize the ArrayList.

        public void add(BillItem billItem) {
            billItems.add(billItem);
        }
    }

}
```

This is where we actually create the `BillItem` class when the response is received.

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static App instance;
    private static ServerAPI serverAPI;

    public static ServerAPI getServerAPI() {
        return serverAPI;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(BillItem.class, new BillItemDeserializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(Bills.class, new BillsDeserializer())
                .create();

        instance = this;
        serverAPI = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ServerAPI.ENDPOINT)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setLog(new RestAdapter.Log() {
                    @Override
                    public void log(String message) {
                        Log.v("Retrofit", message);
                    }
                })
                .build().create(ServerAPI.class);
    }

    // This has nothing inside of it, it still works.
    public class BillItemDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<BillItem> {

        @Override
        public BillItem deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                    JsonDeserializationContext context) throws
                JsonParseException {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class BillsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Bills> {
        @Override
        public Bills deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                 JsonDeserializationContext context) throws
                JsonParseException {
            Bills value = new Bills();
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            json = json.getAsJsonObject().get("report");
            if (json.isJsonArray()) {
                for (JsonElement element : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
                    value.add(gson.fromJson(element, BillItem.class));
                }
            } else {
                JsonElement element = json.getAsJsonObject();
                Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = element.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries) {
                    value.add(gson.fromJson(entry.getValue(), BillItem.class));
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `Subscription` object where we receive the data.

```
Subscription subscription = App.getServerAPI()
        .listBill(String.valueOf(employeeID))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<ServerAPI.Bills>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "ERROR: Value returned: " + e.getMessage());

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ServerAPI.Bills bills) {
                for (ServerAPI.BillItem item : bills.billItems) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onNextBillItem: " + item);
                }
            }

        });
```